# Combine two generic lists of different types

Tags: c#

I have two lists as

```
List <BillDetails>= new List<BillDetails>();  
List<Header>=new List<Header>();

Public class Billdetails  
{    
    public string chargecategory;  
    public string materialcode;  
    public int price;  
    public int quantity;  
}

public class Header  
{  
    public string chargecode;  
    public string customername;  
}
```

These two lists are not linked in any way. But I have to combine them these two into one list and bind it to a gridview.

Please help me in combining or merging these two lists without anything in common between them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using generics without having them have *something* in common... right now they're just completely different. And what's `public class chargecode;` supposed to mean?

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more detail - *how* do you want them to be combined?

Comment: homework? this code doesn't even compile

Comment: The only approach I can think of is to create a parent type/interface like IDisplayableInGridView where said interface/parent includes code, displaytext.

Comment: it was a typo error public class chargecode; i have corrected that.what is the best way to combine both these classes into a single one and bind it to the gridview and at the same time store teh values in the session object. I dont know if this a valid question.

Comment: You could create a class to put in your list that takes an object as a child. Then if you implement ICustomTypeDescriptor you can return a property of the child object based on the type of object and the property requested.This is not as easy as it sounds! http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2011/01/implementing-icustomtypedescriptor-for.html

Comment: If they have nothing at all in common, how do you know which `Header` goes with which `Billdetails`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming they are both in the right order and of the same length (big assumption!) you could zip them up and project to an anonymous type:

```
    List<BillDetails> billDetails = new List<BillDetails>();
    List<Header> headers =new List<Header>();

    var results = billDetails.Zip(headers, (details, header) => 
                                  new { details.chargecategory, details.materialcode, header.chargecode, header.customername })
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: Hello Bob, Can you please share the code with me to achieve this.

Comment: @Janaki - I believe I just did, assuming you can use Linq - you'll also have to include a `using System.Linq;` to your code file for this to compile. What C# version are you working with?

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable both = billDetails.OfType<object>().Concat(headers.OfType<object>());
```