# Concatenation of two object lists in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying hard to find a solution to concatenate two object lists,but failed to implement.

this is my codes

```
 List<dealsobj> mylist = new List<dealsobj>();
 List<itemsobj> mylist1 = new List<itemsobj>();


public class dealsobj
{
    public string Dealname;
    public string Ticketcount;
    public string OriginalPrice;
    public string Dealsticketcount;
    public string dealprice;
    public string totalprice;

    public dealsobj(string v1, string v2,string v3,string v4,string v5,string v6)
    {
        Dealname = v1;
        Ticketcount = v2;
        OriginalPrice = v3;
        Dealsticketcount = v4;
        dealprice = v5;
        totalprice = v6;
      }
    }

public class itemsobj
{
    public string Itemname;
    public string price;
    public string quantity;
       public itemsobj(string v1, string v2, string v3)
         {
           Itemname = v1;
           price = v2;
           quantity = v3;
         }
        }
 mylist.Add(new dealsobj(dealname, tictnum, origpri, dealsticktnu, dp, totamnt));
 mylist1.Add(new itemsobj(itnme, price, quant));
```

I want to concatenate these two lists.I already tried `union` and `concate`.But I got error only.Please help me anyone.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: They are of different `Type`, you cannot concatenate them just like that.

Comment: You want to concatenate two lists of **absolutely different types**. What should be type of item in resulting list?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275366/combine-two-generic-lists-of-different-types

Comment: How are you going to use it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
var result = mylist.Cast<object>().Concat(mylist1.Cast<object>());
```

To unbox it:

```
var list = result.OfType<dealsobj>();
var list1 = result.OfType<itemsobj>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot union two list with different classes, but you can create base class for dealsobj and itemsobj and use `List<base>` for union.

Comment: Not a complete answer. You could cast to `object` or you could create a common interface.

Answer (score 0):

If these are your own classed you can use [operator overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/8edha89s.aspx) to create your own concatenation operator:

```
 public static dealsClass operator +(dealsClass x, itemsClass y) 
   {
      return new dealsClass(x.val1 + y.val1, x.val2 + y.val2);
   }
```